# What are the advantages of a fixed IP address?

Tags: ip, isp

My ISP provides an option to pay for a fixed IP address.  What are the advantages of a fixed IP address?  This relates to a home connection which will be used for general browsing, movie download / streaming, and video calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None that I can see in your scenario.
Fixed IPs make it easier to host a server on your network that is accessible from the internet, but they only make it easier.  I've hosted a server for 5 years using a dynamic address.  I use dynamic DNS to ensure my host is always available.

Answer (score 3):

If they make you pay for a fixed IP, usually that implies they allow you to hosting content from your network.

For example,
I host a media streaming application called Subsonic, Which lets me stream music from my home computer to wherever I am.
I also use it to ssh into my system.

Note: Depending on you connection type, your IP rarely changes anyway. On Comcast, Ive had the same IP for about 2 years now, so for me theres no real need to pay for a static IP

Comment: "If they make you pay for a fixed IP, usually that implies they allow you to hosting content from your network."  What are the functional differences between one that does "allow" you to and one that doesn't?

Comment: Very good point: even if you get the IP via DHCP, it doesn't necessarily mean it changes often or changes at all.